# Command line arguments using if/else statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement, struct, command-line-arguments

I am new to programming and this one has me baffled.

I am writing a function to be called by `main` that takes the command line arguments and stores them in a `struct` to use later. This specific example is for use with image editing, but can be used anywhere.

**Desired performance:** Function takes arguments from the command line. Three specific arguments are identified and checked for: `-h`, `-o` and `-t`. If present they will alter the `struct` values. Arguments `-o` and `-t` store the arguments immediately following them into their respective `struct` fields. Any argument that is not `-h` or does not have `-o` or `-t` preceding it is assumed to be the input file name and stored in `flag->inputFile`. If all arguments are accounted for, then `flag->inputFile` should remain `NULL` and can be tested for in the main function and program terminated if this is true.

**Problem:** When there is no input file specified (using the above parameters) `flag->inputFile` keeps getting set to `-o` when it is included as an argument.

**Solution:** Thanks to Scott this question has been answered by replacing several `if` statements with `else if` has now seemed to fix the problem, and the function appears to be working as desired.
My understanding of what was happening is that the `else` statement was being run in every iteration of `i` unless the `-t` argument was included, since it was the statement immediately before the `else`

The compiler I'm using is gcc and this is my code. (I know my struct is not packed, I'm still trying to get my head around this and can't see how it would result in what I'm seeing. Segmentation fault, yes, but not this?)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct PROMPTFLAGS {
    int help;    // Change from NULL if -h argument present
    char * outputFile;    // Store argument after -o as the output file
    char * inputFile;    // Argument not paired with a flag stored here as input file
    float threshold;    // Stores a value to use in image manipulation in main
};

struct PROMPTFLAGS * parsargs(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    struct PROMPTFLAGS* flag = malloc(sizeof(struct PROMPTFLAGS));
    int i;
    printf("argc: %d\n",argc);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        char * arg = argv[i];
        int str_aft = i+1;    // Allows the next string to be used in this iteration of the loop
        if (strcmp(arg,"-h") == 0) {
            flag->help = 1;
        }
        if (strcmp(arg,"-o") == 0) {    // Changing this to 'else if' seems to be a fix
            flag->outputFile = argv[str_aft];
            i++;        // Skips over next arg since already read by argv[str_aft]
        }
        if (strcmp(arg,"-t") == 0) {    // Changing this to 'else if' seems to be a fix
            flag->threshold = strtod(argv[str_aft],NULL);
            i++;        // Skips over next arg since already read by argv[str_aft]
        }
        else {
            flag->inputFile = arg;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    struct PROMPTFLAGS * flags;
    flags = parsargs(argc, argv);
    printf("Help = %d\n",flags.help);
    printf("Output = %s\n",flags.outputFile);
    printf("Input = %s\n",flags.inputFile);
    printf("Threshold = %s\n",flags.threshold);

return 0;
}
```

I apologise for the poor format of the first version of this question and hope that this edit is better. I have made the functions' desired outcomes and the problem I encountered clearer and removed most of the test prints I had through the code and added some comments. I have also included the solution to my problem (provided by another user) and my understanding of what was happening in the broken code.

If people still think this is a poor question or of no use to anyone else then I'm happy to take it down, but have edited and left it up hoping it can help someone else.

This is my first post on stack overflow and I thank everyone for their help and patience while I learn to code and the best manner to post questions.

Comment: If you haven't done so before, now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger. With it you can step through the code, line by line, while monitoring the variables and their values. The debugger and knowledge of how to use it is an integral part of programming.

Comment: Zero fill `*flag` after allocating.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for that suggestion, I'll spend some time with a debugger now and see what I get.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I increment at the end of each if statement.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Wouldn't the `i++` at the end of the `if` statement and in the     `for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)` result in the needed two increments?
The answer by Scott has done the trick it seems. As I understand it the `else` was only acting in conjunction with the `if` statement for `-t`, meaning that anytime `arg` wasn't `"-t"`, `flag->inputFile = arg` was also run.
Is it considered poor form to answer your own question on stackoverflow to check that once you have found an answer you fully understand it? Sorry.... Noob questions...

Comment: Grasshopper, I must have been blind. Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `flag->inputFile = arg` whenever `arg` is not `"-t"` (the `else` after testing for `"-t"`).  I'm not sure when you want to assign to this field, but I am sure this isn't the right logic for it.  For example, if you wanted to do this when `arg` is none of the other specific flags you are looking for, you should be using `if ... else if ... else if ... else`.

Comment: Yes, and the OP should have seen this behaviour whan running under its debugger:(

Comment: Thank you! Seems so obvious now..... :/